# Не срабатывает функция fadeOut для закрытия окна

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой. На локальном сервере все работает, но вот как залил на сервак, обнаружил, что не срабатывает функция закрытия модального окна (писал сам, не использовал плагины)
Вот здесь можно посмотреть http://exweb-drupal-4.tw1.ru/
Нажмите на кнопку "Заказать звонок" или любую другую, типа "Оформить" 0 окно всплывет, но закрыть не получиться. Может я коряво код написал, чтобы долго не рыть через ctrl+shift+i, вот код скрипта для кнопки "Заказать звонок" в шапке:

```
$(".calling").click(function()
    {
        $("#call").fadeIn();
        $("#bg_opcity").fadeIn();
        $('.close_lists').click(function(){ 
            $('#call').fadeOut();   
            $('#bg_opcity').fadeOut(); });
    });
```

Здесь все просто: при нажатии на кнопку с классом calling, срабатывает fadeIn блока с id call и bg_opcity, где call - окошко, bg_opcity - полупрозрачный оверлей. В принципе, не буду тут расписывать, и так все понятно. У меня есть подозрения на конфликт со скриптами слайдера.
Помогите, пожалуйста, уже голову сломал на этом.

Answer (score 2):

У вас на классе window в 188 строке vovan.css :) стоит "opacity: 1 !important"
как нить по другому этот вопрос решите.

Comment: И навешивайте **click** на **.close_lists** вне **$(".calling").click**